# Django: Redirect to current page after POST method shows re-post warning

Tags: django, redirect, post

I'm so confused at the problem that I have, I wish someone can point out my mistake.

I have a method in views.py that bounds to a template that has a form in it. The code looks like this:

```
def template_conf(request, temp_id):
    template = ScanTemplate.objects.get(id=int(temp_id))
    if request.method == 'GET':
        logging.debug('in get method of arachni.template_conf')    
        temp_form = ScanTemplateForm(instance=template))
        return render_response(request, 'arachni/web_scan_template_config.html', 
                               {
                                'template': template,
                                'form': temp_form,
                               })
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        logging.debug('In post method')
        form = ScanTemplateForm(request.POST or None, instance=template)
        if form.is_valid():
            logging.debug('form is valid')
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/web_template_conf/%s/' %temp_id)
```

The behavior of this page is this: when I press "submit" button, the program enters the `POST` branch, and successfully executed everything in the branch. Then the `HttpResponseRedirect` only redirect to current page(that url is current url, I think should be equal to `.`). After that `GET` branch got executed since I redirect to current page, and the page did return successfully. However, if I refresh the page at this time, the browser returns a confirm warning:

```
The page that you're looking for used information that you entered. 
Returning to that page might cause any action you took to be repeated. 
Do you want to continue?
```

If I confirm, the post data will be posted to the backend again. Seems like the browser is still holding previous POST data. I don't know why this happens, please help. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I'm having the exact same issue.  I have similar code as you, but it only seems to work correctly in Firefox.

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia: Oh, I didn't try firefox before, but seems like firefox DOES do the work. So odd......

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia it's a bug in Chrome 25, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your form action is set to ".", you don't need to do a redirect. The browser warning is not within your control to override. Your code can be greatly simplified:

```
# Assuming Django 1.3+
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render_to_response

def template_conf(request, temp_id):
    template = get_object_or_404(ScanTemplate, pk=temp_id)
    temp_form = ScanTemplateForm(request.POST or None, instance=template)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # optional HttpResponseRedirect here
    return render_to_response('arachni/web_scan_template_config.html', 
           {'template': template, 'form': temp_form})
```

This will simply persist your model and re-render the view. If you want to do an HttpResponse Redirect to a *different* view after you call `.save()`, that will not cause the browser to warn you that the POST data has to be re-submitted.

Also, there's no need, and it's not good practice, to hard-code your URL patterns that you would do a redirect to. Use the `reverse` method from django.core.urlresolvers. It will make your code a lot easier to refactor later, should your URLs need to change.

Comment: Thanks very much for your suggestions. Learned a lot. One question: is 'render' method new in Django 1.4? I'm currently having 1.3 installed.

Comment: Yes, render is only available in 1.4.x+. If you're using 1.3, you'll need to use render_to_response.

Comment: @Andrey 99% of the time I will always do a redirect after a POST request. I'm not sure why the OP wanted to just render the same view over.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you are coming across a bug in Chrome 25 (see [Chromium issue 177855](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177855)), which is handling handling redirection incorrectly. It has been fixed in Chrome 26.

Your original code is correct, although it can be simplified slightly as Brandon suggests. I recommend you *do* [redirect after a successful post request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), as it prevents the user from accidentally resubmitting data (unless their browser has a bug!).

Comment: It's never too late to answer the question! Thanks for the information and confirmation with my code. +1